react navigation header overlap with dynamic island
I am use react-navigation v4 to create a header on our app
"react-navigation": "^4.4.4",  "react-navigation-stack": "^1.10.3",
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack'
import OvertimeAssignSelectShift from '../screens/Dashboard/home/menu/overtime_assign/OvertimeAssignSelectShift'

const StackNavigation = createStackNavigator
(
  {
    OvertimeAssign: {
      screen: OvertimeAssignSelectShift,
      navigationOptions: {
        title: 'Buat Perintah Lembur',
        headerStyle: {
          elevation: 0,
          shadowOpacity: 0,
          shadowColor: "white",
          borderBottomWidth: 0 
        }
      }
    },
  }
)

But somehow i'm having issue with iphone 14 and above, the header is overlap with dynamic island, but it's fine on android
Iphone
Android
Dynamic island is available on iOS 16, so i am using import DeviceInfo from 'react-native-device-info'; to get the iOS Version and set height manual. is there any way to solved this issue ? Thank you
const StackNavigation = createStackNavigator
(
  {
    OvertimeAssign: {
      screen: OvertimeAssignSelectShift,
      navigationOptions: {
        title: 'Buat Perintah Lembur',
        headerStyle: {
          height: Device.iOS <= 16 ? 100 : 0
          elevation: 0,
          shadowOpacity: 0,
          shadowColor: "white",
          borderBottomWidth: 0 
        }
      }
    },
  }
)

